# generating R.JAVA files manually

Tags: java, android, bash, command-line, apk

I need to build R.JAVA files by using command line.there are ways by using several IDEs.but is there any ways or codes to generate R.JAVA files by using command line?

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès doesn't look to be, that answer uses an IDE

Comment: Wrong, that answer suggest you to use ant manually, read more carefully.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [this tutorial](http://geosoft.no/development/android.html)

> In order for the application source code to be able to access the
>   resources within the res/ directory, a class called `R.java` (for
>   Resources) is created.
>
> Use the [Android Asset Packaging Tool](http://elinux.org/Android_aapt) (aapt) to create the `R.java` file:
>
> ```
> ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools/aapt
>                         package
>                         -v
>                         -f
>                         -m
>                         -S DEV_HOME/res
>                         -J DEV_HOME/src
>                         -M DEV_HOME/AndroidManifest.xml
>                         -I ANDROID_HOME/platforms/android-X/android.jar
> ```
>
> The destination location of `R.java` within the src/ tree is determined by the package attribute of the manifest file.

Where the options are:

```
-v  verbose output
-f  force overwrite of existing files
-m  make package directories under location specified by -J
-S  directory in which to find resources.  Multiple directories will be scanned
    and the first match found (left to right) will take precedence.
-J  specify where to output R.java resource constant definitions
-M  specify full path to AndroidManifest.xml to include in zip
-I  add an existing package to base include set
```

And the parameters are:

```
DEV_HOME - the project directory
ANDROID_HOME - Android Software Development Kit installation location
```

Comment: could you please explain in detail(like full code)